# Set the same default background of the UITableView to a custom view controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background

I need to set the same gray stripped background to another view.
Can anyone help me on this one?

Thanks,
Leonardo

Comment: possible duplicate of [is groupTableViewBackgroundColor deprecated on iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's very easy :)

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
```

Comment: Minor correction should be setBackgroundColor but it worked great!! Thanks!

Comment: Someone should create a header file of British #define macros :P

Comment: On iOS 13 and above, use `UIColor.systemGroupedBackground`.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 6.0 the given answer from [Jasarien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118600/242026) will not work anymore. Basically you need to place a `UITableView` in the background to accomplish what you want (do not forget to set the `autoresizingMask` or according contraints in Auto-Layout). You maybe also want to set the property `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` so the user can not interact with your 'background color'.

Comment: See here for sample code that does this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14304358/89989