# Group table view background color is deprecated in ios 6.0

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is groupTableViewBackgroundColor deprecated on iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6)

I am getting this warning on my storyboard in iOS 6. I would hover to see the replacement method, but since I'm viewing the storyboard it shows me nothing. How can I easily set the background color? Seems like I should be able to do this from the Interface Builder.

Comment: I'm getting this warning too, but I'm confused as to what I should be using instead of it, and I can't seem to find any mention of it in the apple release notes.

Comment: @joshaidan see mhdali's answer below. you have to change the background color to something other than "group table view bg color." also -- a decent workaround is to add a new uiview, send it to back, and color it whatever color you want.

Comment: I know I can fix it by changing the colour, but I wish I had an explanation from Apple as to why the colour was removed, and what they recommend doing instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open your storyboard, check all views in the Attributes Inspector and change all views with Grouped Table View background color to any other color, I changed mine to white and all warnings went away.

[image: attributes inspector]

Answer (score 15):

In code you can set it using the following:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: I found your answer after doing a lot of tests on my own and for me the first two lines work fine, no need to use the third one.

Comment: Yes, now I remember. The last line was for changing the colour to transparent. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed, that in iOS simulator the groupTableViewBackgroundColor is not shown in iOS 6 but in iOS 5.
On a device with iOS 6 it still looks like in iOS 5.
An interesting point is, that the simulator still shows the groupTableViewBackgroundColor in grouped tables, so I think it is just not allowed to use this color for other views than grouped table views in iOS 6.

Comment: And that's lucky because I would have had to make an urgent update to fix this, had this background colour really stopped working on iOS6 devices like it has in the simulator. I guess a lot of other apps would also have been affected.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. All solutions I found on the web state that you need to use another color. I actually want to keep using the table view background color, but cannot find anywhere how to do that. If it still works on the device, then I don't need to change anything now.