# cannot get rid of Group Table View Background Color deprecated warning in xib files

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xib, deprecated, ios6

I understand that Group Table View Background Color is deprecated in ios 6.0. My problem is that I cannot seem to get rid of this warning in xib files.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to default ? I had this warning too after setting it to default it went away. http://postimage.org/image/546anhcnv/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also had troubles finding the grouped table views where I assigned this color, because my storyboard is kind of huge. For me this worked:

- Edit the storyboard or XIB files as source (right-click on storyboard, open as source)
- Remove all the occurences of `<color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/>`

Make sure to backup your storyboard of XIBs first.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer already posted.
[Group table view background color is deprecated in ios 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539861/group-table-view-background-color-is-deprecated-in-ios-6-0)

You can't set "Group Table View" color as a background, so you need to pick a new color as your background.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had to fix when I had all these errors was that I wasn't being choosy in my XIB files when picking a clear background; I'd just pick the first clear color image I saw.  When I looked, I had a bunch of labels and stuff using "Group Table View Background Color" as the view's background color.  I just changed them all to "Clear Color" and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem so I opened the storyboard XML file in an editor. ( on the warning, "Open As" -> "Source Code) I searched for the string "groupTableViewBackgroundColor".  Unfortunately, not every instance of this string is a problem because ios 6 still uses this for the background color for table views. In other words, I ignored any instances like this:

```
<tableView key="view"  ... >
    <rect key="frame" .../>
    <autoresizingMask .../>
    <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/>
```

Anywhere else you find groupTableViewBackgroundColor is probably a problem and you can figure out where to fix it on your storyboard from the XML source file.