# Setting background to GroupTableViewBackgroundColor

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitableview

I have a UIViewController in my Monotouch iPhone application and I want to set the background to what you have in a UITableViewStyle.Grouped.  However when I use the code below it returns a black screen.

```
this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.GroupTableViewBackgroundColor;  // Black screen
this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red; // Works
```

I call these in the ViewWillAppear method.  If I comment out the GroupTable then the background gets set to Red.  When I comment out the second line all I get is a black screen.

Does anyone know why this is?  Can you not call UIColor.GroupTableViewBackgroundColor if your not in a UITableViewController?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i have used this on my current project & it works fine i have xcode 4.0 & simulator 4.3 
i have found on net that it is deprecated on ios 6 
i have used like this

```
[self.tableview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
```

just have look at this link [is groupTableViewBackgroundColor deprecated on iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6)

for alternative you can find out same image as UItableview Grouped style background on internet.

Comment: thanks - I'am developing in iOS6 so my problem is that it's deprecated.