# How to get this background strip in IOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimage

[image]

I have used this background in older version, after updated to iOS 6.0 I am not able to find anywhere in IB. I stack overflowed and used this

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

Still it is giving white color, What should I do now? Do I need to set image for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function **groupTableViewBackgroundColor** deprecated on iOS 6. Please set color or image in Background mode
please see the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6)

Comment: Color with those strip. Is it possible?

Comment: possible... please explain your problem or you want ?

Comment: I can set that kind of color, vertical strip (like above) Do I need to draw over it?

Comment: use this self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableViewBackground.png"]];

Comment: and copy the tableViewBackground image from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6