# UITableView : get background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a constant that returns the secondary background color of a `UITableView` with style "grouped" ? That's the gray color here :

[image]

I've tried `UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor` but it returns apparently the background color of the rows (light gray), not of the secondary background color (gray).

Comment: I could hardcode the color rgb components, but that would fail if apple change the default UI colors...

Comment: Ok, found the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6
I mark my question as duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the QuartzCore framework in your app.
2. Import the framework in your .h or .m file
3. Then -

   ```
   tbl.layer.borderColor
   ```

Comment: Does not seems to work... I use `[UIColor colorWithCGColor:myTableView.layer.borderColor]` and it brings me black color

Answer (score 1):

Use `layer` property. try like something this

```
UIColor.groupTableView.layer.borderColor
```

Answer (score 1):

`tableView.separatorColor` gives border color. I think that is you want.

Comment: Maybe i was not precise enough in my question, I want the secondary background color (gray), not the border color